# String formatting of wildcards within output strings

Tags: snakemake

I am relatively new to snakemake, and I am having some trouble adapting a scatter-gather DeepVariant workflow into snakemake rules.

In the original Snakefile, I would like to scatter the first step across a cluster.  DeepVariant uses a `*.00001-of-00256.*` format to track the shard number in an intermediate file format, so I need to use string formatting to supply both the shard number and the total number of shards within `input`, `output`, and `shell` fields, and I provide the shard number as a wildcard in the `params` of the `scatter` rule.  The `expand()` function in the `input` field of the `gather` rule is correctly generating the expected filenames, but it is unable to find the input file paths that would be generated by the `scatter` step.

I have generated a minimal reproducible example below, as well as the output of running this example (lightly redacted to remove some path information).

```py
N_SHARDS = 8

rule all:
    input: "done.txt"


rule scatter:
    input: "start.txt"
    output: f"test_{{shard:05}}-of-{N_SHARDS:05}.txt"
    params:
        shard = range(N_SHARDS)
    message: "scattering"
    shell:
        f"echo {{wildcards.shard}} {N_SHARDS} > {{output}}"


rule gather:
    input: expand(f"test_{{shard:05}}-of-{N_SHARDS:05}.txt", shard=range(N_SHARDS))
    output: touch("done.txt")
    shell: "echo gathering"
```

```sh
$ touch start.txt
$ snakemake -s example.smk -j 1
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 17 of /redacted/example.smk:
Missing input files for rule gather:
test_00002-of-00008.txt
test_00000-of-00008.txt
test_00006-of-00008.txt
test_00001-of-00008.txt
test_00004-of-00008.txt
test_00005-of-00008.txt
test_00007-of-00008.txt
test_00003-of-00008.txt
```

I have built very similar rules for other scatter-gather concepts that do not require string formatting of wild cards, so that is the only thing I can think of that is different in this case.  I would appreciate any insights!

**UPDATE**: A helpful twitter user [noted](https://twitter.com/holtjma/status/1282034308513959937) that I can remove the `:05` in `scatter`->`output` and the rule works.  This is great, and it happens to solve my original problem, but only because DeepVariant is tolerant of zero-padding for the shard parameter passed at the command line.  Is there a solution that allows me to apply formatting to a wildcard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```py
N_SHARDS = '00008'

shard = ['%05d' % x for x in range(int(N_SHARDS))]

wildcard_constraints:
    shard= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in shard])

rule all:
    input: 
        "done.txt",

rule scatter:
    input: 
        "start.txt",
    output:
        "test_{shard}-of-%s.txt" % N_SHARDS,
    shell:
        r"""
        echo {wildcards.shard} %s > {output}"
        """ % N_SHARDS
    
rule gather:
    input:
        expand('test_{shard}-of-%s.txt' % N_SHARDS, shard= shard),
    output: 
        touch("done.txt")
    shell: 
        "echo gathering"
```

The `wildcard_constraints` bit may be redundant but I tend use it quite liberally if I know exactly what values the wildcards are going to take.

One thing: You seem to know before hand how many shards DeepVariant is going to generate (`N_SHARDS = 8` in the example). Is this actually the case? If not, I think you need to resort on the checkpoint functionality of snakemake.